# Magento 1.7 how to rewrite a URL with special characters in such as %20 etc

Tags: magento-1.7, url-rewrite, htaccess, 301-redirect

Someone at the company I work for has added a product in Magento and created a terrible URL with 's and spaces in. They must have entered the product name in the URL field.

The URL looks like this:

/Kickster%20Academy%2016'%20x%207'

Google has indexed this URL so I am trying to add a 301 for it to the correct URL.

My problem is I dont know what to put in the .htaccess file to do this, if I put it in how it is above, the browser swaps out the %20s for spaces and then the URL doesn't get rewritten.

If I swap out the %20's before I put it into the htaccess file then it breaks the .htaccess file as there are spaces where there shouldn't be

Any ideas?